# pandas dropping of words in dataframe

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

I have a sample dataframe that I wish to drop all words and keep the values.

```
Column1    Column2    Column3    Column4                     Column5
5FQ        1.047      S$55.3     UG44.2 as of 02/Jun/2016    S$8.2 mm
```

Is it possible to drop words and keep all the numbers? IE: to get the desired results below:

```
Column1    Column2    Column3    Column4    Column5
5          1.047      55.3       44.2       8.2
```

Comment: You wanna drop `S` from `S$55.3` but not from `S$8.2 mm`? I don't see a pattern!

Comment: @jakewong and "5FQ" doesn't become just "5" ?

Comment: What about the resulting `5FQ` - why doesn't it become `5`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to do:

```
In [212]: df
Out[212]: 
  Column1  Column2 Column3                   Column4   Column5
0     5FQ    1.047  S$55.3  UG44.2 as of 02/Jun/2016  S$8.2 mm

In [213]: df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.extract(r'(\d+\.?\d*)', expand=True).astype(np.float))
Out[213]: 
   Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4  Column5
0      5.0    1.047     55.3     44.2      8.2
```

Comment: Thanks Nehal. Just curious. If for example in `Column2`, the value was `(1.047)`, would it be possible to convert it to `-1.047` instead of just `1.047`?

Comment: @jakewong You could  do: `df = df['Column2'].apply(lambda x: -x)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`pd.Series.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
In [28]: for c in df:
    df[c] = df[c].str.extract('(\d+\.?\d*)', expand=False)
   ....:     

In [29]: df
Out[29]: 
  Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5
0       5   1.047    55.3    44.2     8.2
```

Note that this is a bit brittle, as in `Column4` it works because the date appeared after the quantity. Your question doesn't specify anything more precise, though.